# Ubuntu Touch - which device HW? (OTG USB, CAMERA, WiFi, Call, SMS)

Tags: ubuntu-touch

1. (just wanted to confirm)As of today, are these the only devices that are supported with Ubuntu Touch?

(1.1) https://devices.ubports.com/#/

(1.2) https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/devices/

2. I am mainly looking for a hardware/ubuntu touch device which supports the below:

   2.1 Supports Camera, Call, SMS, WiFi

   2.2 Supports Skype and/or WhatsApp: Either of them

   2.3 Supports OTG USB + Charging at the same time:the reason for this, I am planning to use this for running a zwave application via USB dongle, and at the same time, to be able to charge the phone.

Please let me know.

Many thanks.